# Emulating Excel spreadsheet like behaviour in Flexicious Grid

Tags: excel, apache-flex, flexicious

I was wondering if some of the following functionality which is available in Excel can be duplicated easily in Flexicious Grid, for example:

1) Copy and Paste from an external source - a group of values copied from an Excel Spreadsheet (this might be possible http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/datagrid-support-for-copy-and-paste.html)

2) Quick copy of the contents of one cell to multiple cells - a value in a cell and copy that value to multiple cells easily, with a simple keyboard shortcut or mouse action

3) Look ahead search - autocomplete on input of a value - hold a data structure in memory of certain values and have the value autocomplete when input into a cell

I would be grateful for any feedback on these items.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste works in example link given, but only for Spark datagrid with flex 4.5 and above.